# Find the derivative of $(9x^6+4x^3)^4$

Tags: calculus

I need help to find the derivative of $(9x^6+4x^3)^4 $

I already tried the chain rule but I got the wrong answer and I do not know what I did wrong.

This is what I got:

$$4(9x^6+4x^3)^3 \times 54x^5+12x^2$$

Comment: Hello, The best thing is to show us what you did. We can point out the mistake. That's how we learn

Comment: Neither do we, we can't read above your shoulder.

Comment: 4(9x^6+4x^3)^3 x 54x^5+12x^2 this is what I got

Comment: @DavidRomero You are correct.

Comment: @DavidRomero Apart from the missed brackets, do you have to type the answer in the computer, is it online hw ? Maybe the formatting is the issue

Comment: David Romero: In the future please add things such as the answer you got to **the question body**. Not everybody will see it in a comment. I added it for you this time.

Comment: @S.C.B. Why did you add the parens to David's answer? He didn't have them, and that may exactly have been the error.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Hmm..I didn't see the comment. I thought you made a typo.

Comment: You are just missing parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(g)=g^4,\\
g(x)=9x^6+4x^3.$$

Then

$$\frac{df(g)}{dg}=4g^3,\\\frac{dg(x)}{dx}=54x^5+12x^2$$ and

$$\frac{df(g(x))}{dx}=4g^3(x)(6x^5+12x^2).$$

Answer (score 0):

using the chain and the power rule we get $$4(9x^6+4x^3)^4(54x^5+12x^2)$$
simplifying we obtain $$24x^{11}(9x^3+2)(9x^3+4)^3$$

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is merely missing a pair of parentheses around the $54x^5+12x^2$.  If you weren't already aware how important parentheses can be, hopefully you are now.

I'm guessing this was an exercise done at a computer, and the computer only told you you got it wrong, without any further explanation.  I can't imagine a human grader with a red pen not inking in the correction, even if they are hardnosed and give no partial credit for the attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the chain rule: $\frac{df(y)}{dx}=\frac{df}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Let $y=(9x^6+4x^4)$.
So you get $\frac{d}{dy}(y^4)=4y^3$ and $\frac{d}{dx}(9x^6+4x^4)=54x^5+12x^2$.

So, $\frac{df}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=4y^3(54x^5+12x^2)$. Substitute $y$ back with 
$(9x^6+4x^4)$ and you get:

$4(9x^6+4x^4)^3(54x^5+12x^2)$